# Liking posts in a nosql database (DynamoDb)

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am trying to figure out how I could realise the "liking system" of a social network typed application as cheap as possible (*with the one table approach*). Every time I list a post, I want to show a heart symbol to symbolize if the current post is already liked by the user of my app (like instagram). I think this problem should be valid for all nosql architectures.

I am thinking about these two approaches

**Put each like as a row**

If there is a post with the id ***"hello_post"*** and a user called ***walterwhite***, one like would look like this (no puns intended)

```
Partitionkey: likes#walterwhite
Sortkey: post#hello_post
```

With this way I could get all liked posts of my users and could check if a given post is already liked. The problem I see with this is that it could be expensive since every like would need a write operation and another read operation if I want to check if it is already liked.

**Put likes in an array**

I could make an array which is getting updated each time a post gets liked. This would need a Lambda function which pushs the postid in the like array of the user.

It could look like this:

```
Partitionkey: likes#walterwhite
Sortkey: none
likes: [{post_id:"hello_post",date:"15.08.2019"}, {post_id: abc, date: "15.02.2018"}, ...]
```

This way I could get all likes in one single read operation.

The problem here is that every document is limited by 400KB. It wouldn't scale after a specific time. Furthermore it isn't very flexible since I have to download the complete list of likes to check if I already liked a given post.

What do you think would be the cost efficient way to handle this problem ? Is there any better way to solve it?

PS: I want to aggregate the global like count with a lambda function. So I only need one read for it

Comment: Similar question that has been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53358395/5563569

Comment: Thank you for the link. But unfortunately it's a bit different. The author of this post isn't saying that he has to get/read the likes very often. In my case every time an user scrolls a list of posts, it has to get the info if the user already liked it or not.

Comment: In the solutions described there, you can directly look up a “like” using the postId and the userId. That will be pretty fast. You can also use a single query to get all the likes of a single user or all of the likes of a single post.

Comment: wouldn't this be very expensive ? Each time I look up if the post is liked by the user I would use a read operation. For instance, if an average user looks at 50 posts (scrolling) and I have a Million user => I would need 50M read operations only to get if the post is liked or not. Another 50m read for the post itself. And furthermore isn't the solution the same I posted in my question (first one) ?

Comment: On closer inspection, it does seem to be basically the same solution.

Comment: Whether you use many small items or few larger items, you still pay for the amount of data you are reading, not the actual number of requests you make. If you know something about the posts that are being viewed (ie. are the viewed by date, by category, by author) you may be able to optimize a bit by grouping related data together.

Comment: @MatthewPope But in the documentation it says this : "API calls to read data from your table are billed in read request units.". Am I understanding it wrong ? Thank you for your help and sorry for the late answer

Comment: The consumed RCU also depends on the size of the items. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.CapacityUnits.Read